# How can I find flight history of an old plane with MSN?

Tags: dc-10

I am trying to verify a plane that possibly flew the route between DAC and BKK in the early 80s. It's Thai Airways, DC 10-30,  MSN 46959. It has a pure sentimental value, because a Thai Airways DC 10-30 at DAC is the earliest memory of a beautiful plane I have. I just want to be sure if that's the same plane I remember from my childhood.

Comment: Welcome to aviation.stackexchange.com! What exactly do you want to know? Whether the aircraft with MSN 46959 flew for Thai Airways in the early 80's or that it occasionally flew to DAC, or are you looking for confirmation that this aircraft visited DAC at a specific date? BTW, the aircraft has been converted to a restaurant in Accra, 

Comment: Hi, I just wanted to know if that flew to/from DAC anytime in the 80s. If not that MSN, then which DC-10 THAI AIRLINES did. I went to see off my dad, and saw a DC 10 was being refuelled. All because to validate a memory, to know which exact plane gave me the feeling/dream of being somewhere far away, as if in its presence I felt a call. That's why I am searching that plane.